# How to enable ZuulProxy in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, applicationcontext, netflix-zuul

I am trying to implement Spring Cloud Netflix zuul proxy in my application. In internet, i am getting all option where it's implemented using spring boot. To enable zuul proxy, in spring boot, it's done -

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudZuulExampleApplication {
```

But my application is spring mvc application and i have xml based configuration. Now I am not understanding how to do @EnableZuulProxy in my application-context.xml file.

Zuul proxy is used to route the traffic. More details about it can be found at - https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/spring-cloud-zuul-example/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Netflix is fully dependent on Spring boot. So it can't be used without Spring Boot. 
You can consider migrating your Spring MVC application to Spring Boot application. Or you may consider using Netflix Zuul that is not dependent on Spring Boot.